# Prove that: $\csc 48° + \csc 96° + \csc 192° + \csc 384°=0$

Tags: trigonometry

Prove that: $\csc 48° + \csc 96° + \csc 192° + \csc 384°=0$

My Attempt:

$$L.H.S=\csc 48°+\csc 96°+\csc 192°+\csc 384°$$
$$=\csc (90^{\circ}-42^{\circ})+\csc (90^{\circ}+6^{\circ})+\csc (180^{\circ}+12^{\circ}) +\csc (360^{\circ}+24^{\circ})$$
$$=\sec 42° + \sec 6° - \csc 12° + \csc 24°$$

How do I complete the proof?

Comment: Did you look at the preview at all before posting this cloud of MathJax errors?

Comment: @HenningMakholm, Sorry I didn't see. But, \cosec isn't it the correct format?

Comment: You should write `\csc`, instead, which produces $\csc$. It is also the more common way to denote the cosecant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

$\csc2A+\cot2A=\dfrac{1=\cos2A}{\sin2A}=\cdots=\cot A\iff\csc2A=\cot A-\cot2A$

Set $2A=48^\circ,96^\circ,192^\circ,384^\circ$

Use $384=360+24$

Comment: where and how to use $384=360+24$?

Comment: @LeonhardEuler, Have u set the values of $2A$ and added?

Comment: yes done till there!!

Comment: @LeonhardEuler, What have you found?

Comment: @LeonhardEuler, Replacing $2A$ with $2x,4x,8x,16x$ we get $$\cot16x=\cot x\implies16x=n180^\circ+x\iff x=12^\circ n$$ where $n$ is any integer, $15\nmid n$. Here $n=2$

Comment: Sorry, here $$n=4$$